# Is it safe to delete the Python312 folder?

Tags: python, windows, installation, uninstallation

I recently uninstalled Python 3.12.1 using settings but the installation directory is still there, which was `C:\Users\woskethebot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312`.

The folder has the contents:

```
Python312
├───Lib
│   └───site-packages
│       ├───<insert site packages here>
└───Scripts
    └───__pycache__
    └───<insert files here>
```

Note: I am using Windows 11.

I uninstalled both Python launcher and Python 3.12.1 using Settings > Apps > Apps & features. I expected it to delete the entire Python folder. It only removed some stuff in the Python312 folder leaving the folders "Lib" and "Scripts" intact.

Comment: If you don't need them for anything and have not saved any of your own files there (you should not) then absolutely.

Comment: Installers generally only track files created by it, including the program itself, not including files through the program after the fact. Think of a word processor, it may be problematic if the uninstall program also deletes all the documents created through the word processor.